# Selecting data from a database according to the locale language in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have posts stored in my database as seen below and I would like to fetch records based on the locale.

```
id       title-ar      title-en       body-ar     body-en   
---------------------------------------------------------
1        خبر جديد      new post      مرحبا      hello      
2        اخر الاخبار    last news    مرحبا       hello
```

Assuming I would want to load data for the language Arabic or English, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Newish to laravel here too so if it was me I'd do 2 queries (and I know there is probably a better way to do it but I'd do something like this):

```
$englishPosts = Table::all()->select('title-en', 'body-en'); 
$arabicPosts = Table::all()->select('title-ar', 'body-ar');
```

Then return them to a view (blade) or  vue/react component and display them that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have **getLanguageCode()** method which is returning me the en, ar, fr or any selected language name which I am using to concatinate along with my column name. Like

```
DB::table('faqs')->selectRaw('title_' . getLanguageCode() . ' as title, description_' . getLanguageCode() . ' as description')->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();
```

Here is the code for **getLanguageCode()** into my Helper file which I can call directly without any reference.

```
function getLanguageCode() {
    return LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
}
```